# Pandas: categorize column values by range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df like this

```
a  b  c
1  0  2
5  7  8
4  1  3
3  4  6
5  2  5
.......
```

Now I want to replace those data with following ranges

```
0-3 = 1
4-6 = 2
7-9 = 3
```

Column values are less than 10, so the range is within 0-9.

I want to replace the above dataframe values with the range categories and output should be like this

```
a  b  c
1  1  1
2  3  3
2  1  1
1  2  2
2  1  2
.......
```

So if any value in the df is within 0-3 should be replaced by 1, and if anything within 4-6 replace it by 2 and so on.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `pd.cut` with `apply`  i.e

```
df.apply(lambda x : pd.cut(x,[-1,3,6,9],labels=[1,2,3]))
```

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  3  3
2  2  1  1
3  1  2  2
4  2  1  2
```

A non-apply based solution suggested by @coldspeed :

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.cut(df.values.reshape(-1,),[-1,3,6,9],labels=[1,2,3]).codes.reshape(df.shape)+1,columns=df.columns)
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.cut(np.hstack(df.values),[-1,3,6,9],labels=[1,2,3]).codes.reshape(df.shape)+1,columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Courtesy upvote :-) pd.cut is the politically correct way to do this.

Comment: Haha you use really fancy words sometimes. Thank you

Comment: Get rid of the apply. Use `pd.cut(df.values.reshape(-1, ),[-1,3,6,9],labels=[1,2,3]).codes.reshape(df.shape)`. And then load the result into a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  we need to add +1 after reshaping .

Answer (score 4):

Using a little mathemagic:

```
((df - 1) // 3).clip(0) + 1

   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  3  3
2  2  1  1
3  1  2  2
4  2  1  2
```

---

Alternatively, `replace` all zeros with one (the only corner case to deal with) and then divide.

```
(df.replace(0, 1) - 1) // 3 + 1

   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  3  3
2  2  1  1
3  1  2  2
4  2  1  2
```

Comment: Nice solution ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)

```
In [5942]: bins = np.array([0, 4, 7, 10])

In [5943]: pd.DataFrame(np.digitize(df, bins), columns=df.columns)
Out[5943]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  3  3
2  2  1  1
3  1  2  2
4  2  1  2
```

Or as

```
In [5947]: bins2 = np.array([-1, 3, 6, 9])

In [5948]: pd.DataFrame(np.digitize(df, bins2, right=True), columns=df.columns)
Out[5948]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  3  3
2  2  1  1
3  1  2  2
4  2  1  2
```